# PowerShell: How to pass dynamic variable to Get-Counter

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, process

I am trying to add computerName, processName dynamically through a variable in `Get-Counter` of PowerShell But it is throwing an error. As I am new to PowerShell, I am unaware how to concat it. Can you please help me in resolving the issue?

Below is the code I am trying to do

```
$compName = 'mycomputer'
$processName = 'code'

$url2='"\\'+$compName+'\process('+$processName+'#1)\id process" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'
Get-Counter $url2
```

`$url2` output must look like:

`Get-Counter '\\mycomputer\process(code#4)\id process' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` -> Here is what I want to execute through dynamic url

Error:

> ```
> Get-Counter : The specified counter path could not be interpreted.
> At C:\mycomputer\Main\process\pws.ps1:93 char:17
> +      $recData = Get-Counter $url2
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
> ```

Comment: @Paxz Added output Please see above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a single string as a positional argument, PowerShell will interpret it as just that - one single argument.

Beyond that, your "dynamic" argument won't work because it's using single-quotes, and so the `$compName` and `$processName` variables won't expand!

Either do:

```
$url2 = "\\$compName\process($processName#1)\id process"
Get-Counter $url2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

or use splatting:

```
$GetCounterParams = @{
    Counter = "\\$compName\process($processName#1)\id process"
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
}
Get-Counter @GetCounterParams
```

Comment: But I am unable to get its output in variable like: $output =Get-Counter @GetCounterParams Not working for me

Comment: Is there any thing we can Do for it?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "Not working for me" - do you get any errors? Is it hanging? Does `$output` contain anything afterwards?

Comment: I want the output of this code in a variable. But the variable is blank on next line. It is executing after some time. I think I need a callback or setTimeout for it. As my mainstream is JS I don't have any knowledge of syntax in PowerShell

Comment: or else we can wrap it in function?